# What is the typical size for an extended public key?

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, xpub

What is the typical bytesize range for an extended public key?

An extended private key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An extended public or private key is always 78 bytes of data. When Base58 Check encoded, this results in a string that is up to 112 characters in size.

The format of the data is defined in [BIP 32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#serialization-format).

Comment: is there any lower bound ? or is it arbitrary -> I have tried to generate like few thousands of extended keys and they are all 111 characters in size - Is this the rule or can it be less/more?

Comment: It should be a fixed size.